# How can get text which is a symbol in a tag using selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want each user rating from [this link](https://www.zomato.com/ncr/salad-days-dlf-cyber-city-gurgaon):

**data-iconr="ù" this produce rating** 4.0 or anything

you can have look on div tag

```
<div class="left bold zdhl2 tooltip icon-font-level-7" data-iconr="ù">Rated</div>
```

Is there any way to get rating of each user?

Also, how I can get xpath of div tag because it changes the class of each div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be bullet-proof, but, you can rely on the class name of the element, it changes with the rating  - e.g. for `5.0` there is `icon-font-level-9` class, for `4.5` - `icon-font-level-8` etc.

Implementation:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/ncr/salad-days-dlf-cyber-city-gurgaon")

mapping = {
    "icon-font-level-9": 5.0,
    "icon-font-level-8": 4.5,
    "icon-font-level-6": 3.5
    # ... TODO
}

pattern = re.compile(r"icon-font-level-\d+")
for review in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[itemprop=review]"):
    author = review.find_element_by_css_selector("div[itemprop=author] div[itemprop=name] a").text

    rating_class = review.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[. = 'Rated']").get_attribute('class')
    rating = mapping.get(pattern.search(rating_class).group(0))
    print author, rating
```

Prints:

```
Vandhna Babu 4.5
Mohit Yadav 3.5
Pulkit1283 4.5
Grub Society 5.0
Joel George 5.0
```